# differentiate int and double in intellij template

Tags: intellij-idea, velocity

I am defining a custom toString template in IntelliJ. IntelliJ offers a template system based on the Velocity scripting language. Great stuff !

But I am facing a particular issue with it right now. I need to tell the difference between an `int` field and a `double` field. Essentially to generate something like (simplified):

```
public String toString() {
  String output = "";
  output += "myIntField:" + Util.intDescription(myIntField);
  output += "myDblField:" + Util.doubleDescription(myDblField);
  return output;
}
```

For the `Integer` type it works fine, but I can't seem to get it to work for primitive `int`.

```
#if ($member.typeQualifiedName == "java.lang.Integer")
...
#end
#if ($member.typeName == "Integer")
...
#end
```

I can make constructs with methods like `$member.primitive` and `$member.numeric` but none of them makes a distinction between `double` and `int`.

The [documentation of IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-tostring-settings-dialog.html) gives me the impression that I'm at a dead end.

*PS: Sure it could be solved, by changing the java code/api, which can simplify the required format for the `toString()` method. But that's really a last resort for me.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#elseif ( $member.type == 'double' )
output += "myDoubleField:" + Util.doubleDescription(myDoubleField);
#elseif ( $member.type == 'int' )
output += "myIntField:" + Util.intDescription(myIntField);
```

For whatever reason the $member.isDouble property isn't accessible for me. It's not listed in [IntelliJ's docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-tostring-settings-dialog.html), the [VTL Reference](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/vtl-reference.html) or the [VTL User Guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html), nor is .type.

I first printed out $member and it listed all the properties on this object. I'm not sure why it listed isDouble though.